# Fail to savetoMongoDB :java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.hadoop.io.BSONWritable

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to convert data from Dataframe to RDD, and save it to MongoDB, here is my code:

```
import pymongo
import pymongo_spark
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark import BasicProfiler
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

class MyCustomProfiler(BasicProfiler):
    def show(self, id):
        print("My custom profiles for RDD:%s" % id)

conf = SparkConf().set("spark.python.profile", "true")
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.master("local[*]") \
.appName("Word Count") \
.config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
.getOrCreate()
# Important: activate pymongo_spark.
pymongo_spark.activate()

on_time_dataframe = spark.read.parquet(r'\data\on_time_performance.parquet')
on_time_dataframe.show()

# Note we have to convert the row to a dict to avoid https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/HADOOP-276
as_dict = on_time_dataframe.rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict())
as_dict.saveToMongoDB('mongodb://localhost:27017/agile_data_science.on_time_performance')
```

some errors occurs:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling 
z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.hadoop.io.BSONWritable
```

I have installed the Mongo-hadoop file; It seems I don't have a Bsonweitable class. I'm not good at java, So I want someone to help me.